# Increase the time to live of a cached plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, optimization, plan-cache

I'm looking at the Plan Cache in SQL Server. I've got a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[CountDescriptions](@Description varchar(1))
AS
    SELECT ID 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE Description = @Description
GO
```

If I execute it and immediately check the cache it's generally there, but it seems to expire very quickly and get removed.

This is making it a bit of a pain to play with.  Is there a way to artificially change a plan's details to stop the garbage collector (*not sure if that's the right word for it*) from deleting it so quickly?

Maybe increasing it's cost to compile or something?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't evict plans from the cache unless there's some sort of memory pressure, generally speaking.  Have a look here for more information:

[Plan Cache Internals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293624.aspx)

This is a little out of date, but the same principles apply.

Comment: Plans get evicted for a myriad of reasons.  In my experience, memory pressure is one of the absolute least common reasons.  Stats updates and index rebuilds are by far the most common, unless you are running a server with an incredibly small amount of memory.  The query in the example would probably be considered TRIVIAL and not even get optimized.

Comment: Absolutely true.  I was assuming that he wasn't doing those things in the meantime, but possible.